# How I can create a CRUD (like scaffold) for Users with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activescaffold

I just wanna that an admin can create, read, update,and delete (CRUD) normal users with the gem devise.
I saw a tutorial with scaffold, but scaffold is just for CRUD, not for a login :/
I know, this question its so bad, but I not have idea

Comment: I would recommend reading this a few times: [Routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Maybe take some tutorials on youtube. In my opinion it will be a good idea to understand CRUD (dataflow etc.) and then try to build what you're requesting. CRUD is also for login. create-read-update-delete a login-cookie, you could say. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' generators are meant to get you up and running quickly and, by no means, are meant to replace writing code. You could create this admin-like ability easily by using http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html and then hand-writing (scary) the controller and views yourself.

But if you want to cheat, `rails g scaffold_controller User email:string`

Comment: I created a project, and I already have devise with a migrated table, do I have to do the scaffold_controller first?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, no. Since you're new to Rails you may find Michael Hartl's legendary Rails Tutorial a great resource. https://www.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 0):

## [Using callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)

not generating anything, just write your code logic in the following callback, inside your model

> 3.1 Creating an Object

```
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_create
around_create
after_create
after_save
after_commit/after_rollback
```

> 3.2 Updating an Object

```
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_update
around_update
after_update
after_save
after_commit/after_rollback
```

> 3.3 Destroying an Object

```
before_destroy
around_destroy
after_destroy
after_commit/after_rollback
```

## [Generate Devise Controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

```
rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```